# LINQ to XML: suppressing redundant namespace attribute in child nodes

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

If a node belongs to a namespace, it's children by default belong to the same namespace. So there's no need to provide an `xmlns` attribute on each child, which is good.

However.

If I create two nodes like this:

```
Dim parent = <parent xmlns="http://my.namespace.org"/>
Dim child = <child xmlns="http://my.namespace.org">value</child>

parent.Add(child)

Console.WriteLine(parent.ToString)
```

The result is this:

```
<parent xmlns="http://my.namespace.org">
  <child xmlns="http://my.namespace.org">value</child>
</parent>
```

But, if create them in a less convenient way:

```
Dim parent = <parent xmlns="http://my.namespace.org"/>
Dim child As New XElement(XName.Get("child", "http://my.namespace.org")) With {.Value = "value"}

parent.Add(child)

Console.WriteLine(parent.ToString)
```

The result is more desirable:

```
<parent xmlns="http://my.namespace.org">
  <child>value</child>
</parent>
```

Obviously, I'd prefer to use the first way because it is so much more intuitive and easy to code. There's also another reason to not use method 2 -- sometimes I need to create nodes with `XElement.Parse`, parsing a string that contains an `xmlns` attribute, which produces exactly same results as method 1.

So the question is -- how do I get the pretty output of method 2, creating nodes as in method 1? The only option I see is to create a method that would clone given XElement, effectively recreating it according to method 2 pattern, but that seems ugly. I'm looking for a more obvious solution I overlooked for some reason.

Comment: @GSerg: Does the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh...namespaces - they will be the death of me.

Here you go:

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://my.namespace.org"
Dim parent = <<%= ns + "parent" %>/>
Dim child = <<%= ns + "child" %>>value</>
parent.Add(child)
```

---

To be able to use `XElement.Parse` and keep child nodes in sync with their parent nodes' namespaces, it's best to use global namespaces. Really easy to do in VB.NET. At the top of your module/class, just use an Imports  and all parents and children will use this namespace. For example:

```
Imports <xmlns="http://my.namespace.org">
Module Main
    Sub SomeSub()
        Dim child = <child>value</child>
        Dim parent = <parent><%= child %></parent>
        Console.WriteLine(parent.ToString)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Note that the `<child/>` element is created first. The same would apply to a non-default namespace, like `Imports <xmlns:p="http://parent.namespace.org">` and then creating with `<p:child/>` and `<p:parent/>`.

I once read, but have yet to find again, that mixing XML Literals with I-don't-know-what-you-call-it-but-it's-that-`parent.Add(something)`-thing is a bad idea.

Comment: That's a great trick! A bit messy in the literals, but the output is cleaner.

Comment: The trick is nice indeed, but it only addresses the problem partially. If I've got an XML string which I parse, the output contains namespaces for child nodes. So I was looking for a way to set some sort of I-don't-want-these flag against an already constructed node rather than a special way to construct a node -- because I cannot use that special way sometimes. Yet I'm happy to accept this answer if no other solution exists.

Comment: @GSerg: Ah, I getcha now. I've updated the answer with what I hope will work for you.